# Как остановить таймер когда он доходит до 00:00:00?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуста как остановить таймер когда он доходит до  00:00:00, сейчас он идет дальше в минус. Спасибо, в js я новичек

```js
function timer() {
    const newData = new Date('Mar 31 2023 00:00:00');

    const daysVal = document.querySelectorAll('.time-count__days .time-count__val');
    const hoursVal = document.querySelectorAll('.time-count__hours .time-count__val');
    const minutesVal = document.querySelectorAll('.time-count__minutes .time-count__val');
    const secondsVal = document.querySelectorAll('.time-count__seconds .time-count__val');

    const normalize = (n) => n <= 9 ? `0${n}` : n

    const timeCount = () => {
        let now = new Date();
        let leftUntil = newData - now;

        let days = normalize(Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24));
        let hours = normalize(Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24);
        let minutes = normalize(Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        let seconds = Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000) % 60;

        daysVal.forEach(dayVal => {
            dayVal.innerHTML = days.toString().replace(/\d/gi, (substring) => `<span>${substring}</span>`);
        });
        hoursVal.forEach(hourVal => {
            hourVal.innerHTML = hours.toString().replace(/\d/gi, (substring) => `<span>${substring}</span>`);
        });
        minutesVal.forEach(minuteVal => {
            minuteVal.innerHTML = minutes.toString().replace(/\d/gi, (substring) => `<span>${substring}</span>`);
        });
        secondsVal.forEach(secondVal => {
            secondVal.innerHTML = seconds.toString().replace(/\d/gi, (substring) => `<span>${substring}</span>`);
        });

    };

    timeCount();
    setInterval(timeCount, 1000);
}
timer()
```

```css
.time-count__content{
  display: flex;
}

.time-count__item{
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

.time-count__val{
  font-size: 40px;
}

.time-count__text{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="time-count">
  <div class="time-count__content">
    <div class="time-count__item time-count__days">
      <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
      <div class="time-count__text">д</div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-count__item time-count__hours">
      <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
      <div class="time-count__text">ч</div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-count__item time-count__minutes">
      <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
      <div class="time-count__text">м</div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-count__item time-count__seconds">
      <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
      <div class="time-count__text">с</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держи вот такой таймер. t хранит общее время в миллисекундах. Условие проверяет t, когда он ноль или ниже, очищает интервал и функция останавливается.

JS

```
function timer(id, deadLine) {
  function getTimeRemaining(endTime) {
    let DAYS, HOURS, MINUTES, SECONDS;

    const t = Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse(new Date());

    if (t <= 0) {
      DAYS = 0;
      HOURS = 0;
      MINUTES = 0;
      SECONDS = 0;
    } else {
      DAYS = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      HOURS = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      MINUTES = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      SECONDS = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    }

    return {
      t,
      DAYS,
      HOURS,
      MINUTES,
      SECONDS,
    };
  }

  function getZero(num) {
    if (num >= 0 && num < 10) {
      return `0${num}`;
    }

    return num;
  }

  function setClock(selector, endTime) {
    const timer = document.querySelector(selector);
    const days = timer.querySelector('#days');
    const hours = timer.querySelector('#hours');
    const minutes = timer.querySelector('#minutes');
    const seconds = timer.querySelector('#seconds');

    updateClock();
    const timeInterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);

    function updateClock() {
      const t = getTimeRemaining(endTime);

      days.innerHTML = getZero(t.DAYS);
      hours.innerHTML = getZero(t.HOURS);
      minutes.innerHTML = getZero(t.MINUTES);
      seconds.innerHTML = getZero(t.SECONDS);

      if (t.t <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timeInterval);
      }
    }
  }

  setClock(id, deadLine);
}

//Вызов функции.

timer('.timer', '2023-04-15');
```

HTML

```
<div class="timer">
   <div class="timer__block">
       <span id="days">12</span>
       дней
   </div>
   <div class="timer__block">
       <span id="hours">20</span>
       часов
   </div>
   <div class="timer__block">
       <span id="minutes">56</span>
       минут
   </div>
   <div class="timer__block">
       <span id="seconds">20</span>
       секунд
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не могли бы вы добавить html к коду?не пойму немного как написать html

Comment: @powerg Добавить html.

Comment: @powerg в deadLine пишите дату в формате "2023-03-25"